# spark-cassandra-connector, limit retry attempts to a dead cassandra node

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

@here : we run cassandra in kuberenetes, and use spark-cassandra connector , the problem we face is for kubernetes POD restarts ,cassandra IP changes

whenever there is a cassandra ip change (cassandra restart)
From worker logs ,  we  see old ip as DOWN and we can see New replaced IP as newly added node , and connections are being made to new pod with correct POD_IP which is correct , but the problem is we also see connections still going to old pod_ip 
and try is still happening to old dead pod_ip

```
com.datastax.driver.core.Host.STATES: Defuncting Connection[/100.96.1.4:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] because: [/100.96.1.4:9042] Cannot connect
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/100.96.1.4:9042] Cannot connect
```

any spark cassandra connector retry attempt i can set to limit no.of retry attempts to a dead node
this warning i see only in spark-worker log
any reconnection policy similar to the one in java driver we can configure in spark-cassandra-connector ?

Comment: why you do not have a service in front of the pod?

Comment: this issue should be solved with a new SCC that was announced yesterday

Comment: just fyi: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/pull/1233

Comment: @Suren : we do have a service, still spark-connector retries dead cassandra pod ip's .that seems to be a default behavior

Comment: @AlexOtt: Thanks for the fix, any idea/time line when this will be merged and available for use, also could you let us know which spark-connector versions this will be applied. .

Comment: I don’t know about timeline, but hopefully soon. It will be available only in upcoming connector 3.0